# How to get the current selected item position using TabLayout in Android Design Library

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am using the android design library TabLayout in that how can I get the current selected item tab position.

```
  ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);      
  MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 22.2.1 of the Support library the [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) has a method `getSelectedTabPosition`.

[Source 1](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj) | [Source 2](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/22.2.1/changes.html#AndroidDev)

Comment: +1 voteup for your effort... but you can also write it on comment ... or you can also edit my answer ...

Answer (score 3):

You can call ViewPager's [`getCurrentItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) to get the index of the currently displayed item.

Comment: Is it possible to get the current item position using TabLayout instance or else can I get the ViewPager instance from the TabLayout

Comment: Unfortunately [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) does not expose any similar methods. Since you already have to get a reference to your ViewPager, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
  mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated 29-07-2016]**

**Refer the accepted answer because below answer is deprecated. If you are using older version then refer it.**

You can do it easily ...

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    pos = tab.getPosition();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: where pos is your integer variable where you want to store the position

Comment: Note that this will likely break your `ViewPager`'s behavior, as `setupWithViewPager()` calls `setOnTabSelectedListener()` and you can only have one such listener. You will want to pass events from this listener on to your ViewPager if you go with this method.